# Data type DIR isn't recognized in VScode (<error-type> DIR)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, directory

I'm using VScode and data type DIR is recognized as error type. Also variables of this type aren't advised in autocompleting but everything works completely as it should. What could be the issue and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Does your code compile?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes it does and works completely fine

Comment: Your editor is trying to be too smart for its own good.